# SQL get last hour from given hour

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wish, from a given date, to be able to have the last hour "round". For example, if it's 8:49 am, I would like a variable to take the value 8:00 am.

Any idea on how to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try offsetting the input by the difference to the start of the hour:

```
SELECT DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, '2020-07-10 08:49:00'), 0);
```

This returns:

```
2020-07-10 08:00:00.000
```